# How to reload div with other SQL query when submiting form?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, post

I have a `HTML` `form` (using as searchbox) and when I submit this `form` with a word inside I want to reload a div with the result of research.

**For example:**

In my div, I have a query like this :

```
SELECT * FROM users;
```

and I display all the `ids`, `names`, etc.

And when I submit the form I want to have a query like this :

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name=$_POST['search'];
```

and display in my div users who are matching to the research without reload all the page but just this div.

How can I do this please?

Comment: You can do this using `ajax`. N.B. You will be shot down for using `name=$_POST`. Please use `PDO` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function. I wrote to you a simple use of this function, I hope that you are a guiding light to solve the problem:

**Of course, you need to change the links to your work environment.**

**index.php**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

if (isset($_GET["search"])) {
    $sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT name FROM users WHERE name = '{$_GET["search"]}'");
    $sth->execute();
    $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $response = array();
    foreach ($result as $responseIndex => $responseValue) {
        $response[] = $responseValue["name"];
    }
    die(implode(",", $response));
}
?>

<form method="GET" action="http://localhost/test/index.php">
    <input name="search" type="text" id="search-value" />
    <input type="submit" id="search-button"/>
</form>

<div id="container"></div>

<script>
    $("#search-button").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#container").load("http://localhost/test/index.php?search=" + $("#search-value").val());
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

index.php

```
<form method="GET" action="http://localhost/test/index.php">
    <input name="search" type="text" id="search-value" />
    <input type="button" id="search-button"/>
<div id="container"></div>
</form>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#search-button').click(function () {
                                        var searchval = $("#search-value").val();
                                        $.post('search.php', {'search_val': searchval, 'action': 'search'}, function (data) {
                                            $("#container").html(data);
                                        });


          });
    });

</script>
```

search.php

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

if (isset($_POST["search"])) {

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT name FROM users WHERE name = '".$_POST['search_val']."'");
    $sth->execute();
    $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $response = array();
    foreach ($result as $responseIndex => $responseValue) {
        $response[] = $responseValue["name"];
    }
    die(implode(",", $response));
}
?>
```